# How to create a schedule in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, gantt

I need to create this schedule in beamer, but I have no idea, because I am learning to use it

[image]

Comment: Use `tabular` to create the table; use `\cellcolor` from `colortbl` package to change color of an individual cell.

Answer (score 5):

The [luaprogtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luaprogtable) that I wrote is intended to deal with large and complicated table like this. Here is an example of using the package to reduce workload (LuaLaTeX needed!):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% the package is new, so it is unlikely to be included
% in your TeX distribution. You can download it form
% https://github.com/xziyue/luaprogtable
\usepackage{luaprogtable}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

% create a table with 24 columns
\LPTNewTable{schedule}{24}{|*{24}{c|}}[
    default after line=\hline,
    nrows=16
]
% set current table
\LPTSetCurrentTable{schedule}
% add horizontal line before first line
\LPTSetRowProp{1}{before line=\hline}

\LPTSetCell{1, 1}[3,1]{\multirow{3}{*}{No.}}
\LPTSetRowProp{1}{after line=\cline{2-24}}
\LPTSetCell{1,2}[1,23]{\multicolumn{23}{c|}{Title}}
\LPTSetCell{2,2}[2,1]{\multirow{2}{*}{Activities}}
\LPTSetRowProp{2}{after line=\cline{3-24}}
\begin{lptview}{2,3:}
{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{August}}[-4]
{\multicolumn{5}{c|}{September}}[-5]
{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{October}}[-4]
{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{November}}[-4]
{\multicolumn{5}{c|}{December}}[-5]
\end{lptview}

% latex3 code to fill the table quickly
\ExplSyntaxOn
% list the "activities"
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetuer,adipiscing,elit,aenean,commodo,ligula,eget,dolor}
% start filling the table
\int_step_inline:nn {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist} {
    % set number indices
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {\int_eval:n {3+#1}, 1} {#1}
    % set activities
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {\int_eval:n {3+#1}, 2} {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}}
}

% fill the numbers
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {1234123451234123412345}
\int_step_inline:nn {\tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl} {
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {3,\int_eval:n {2+#1}} {\tl_item:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}}
}

% now, declare a command to change cell color
\newcommand{\togglecell}[2]{
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {\int_eval:n {3+#1},\int_eval:n {2+#2}} {\exp_not:n{\cellcolor{blue!50}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\togglecell{1}{1}
\togglecell{5}{12}

% use the table
\LPTUseTable
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you are not interested in the package, you can refer to the LaTeX source generated by the code above (if you feel comfortable editing something like this)

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{24}{c|}}
\hline 
\multirow {3}{*}{No.} & \multicolumn {23}{c|}{Title} \\\cline {2-24}
 & \multirow {2}{*}{Activities} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{September} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{October} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{December} \\\cline {3-24}
 &  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline 
1 & lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
2 & ipsum &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
3 & dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
4 & sit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
5 & amet &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
6 & consectetuer &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
7 & adipiscing &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
8 & elit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
9 & aenean &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
10 & commodo &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
11 & ligula &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
12 & eget &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
13 & dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
\end{tabular}
```